# I detach the database, but can't attach it

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019

I am using `Visual Studio 2019`, I right click my MSSQL Local Web Server Database named "`UserDB`" then I click `detach`. After that database is gone and `UserDB.mdf` file is created. But when I want to `attach` this database, I can't find an `attach` option in right click option of `Databases` folder. How can I `attach` the `UserDB` database?

Comment: Have you tried using SSMS (sql server management studio)?

Comment: @thebjorn no, but the tutorials in the internet, there is a attach option when right click the Database folder.

Comment: [Attach a Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: *the tutorials* -- Which tutorial in particular?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this might be a remote database which would not have access to your local file system. The other possibility is the .MDF file may not have a .LDF file that matches. Make sure both files have an identical date and time stamp else it will not work. A limitation on SSMS is the path cannot be too deep. I'd recommend placing the two files into the data directory where the other database files are. Then try attaching.